# Invalid size of UINavigationController (nested in UITabBarController), after pop operation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

**Context:** In our app we have `UITabBarController` as the root, and then each tab view controller is wrapped in dedicated `UINavigationController`. We've added a brand new custom pop/push transition animation to all `UINavigationController` in our app.

**Issue**: Whenever we push a view controller, which has `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`, upon popping it we see that `UINavigationController` view size is reduced by the height of the tab bar. Switching to other tabs we observe that those tabs also were affected - they also have reduced height. That means, that the issue lies with `UITabBarController` itself. For some reason, it decides to subtract the height of tab bar from the available height for its children, which affects how `UINavigationController` and its children are laid out (see screenshots below).

**1.** Initial state, before any view controllers are pushed into the navigation stack.
[image]

**2.** View controller, which hides tab bar, is pushed.
[image]

**3.** View controller, which hides tab bar, is popped.
[image]

Configuration of root `UITabBarController`:

[image]

Configuration of `UINavigationController` used as the root of tab:

[image]

**Observations:**

- The aforementioned effect exists even when complexity is reduced to the bare bones - no custom classes are used and the transition animation merely alters the horizontal position of the views.
- We have tried enabling `Under Opaque Bars` for `UINavigationController`, but in this case, view height is reduced not by the height of `UITabBar`, but by the height of the bottom safe area (34 points).

We are quite lost and would be extremely thankful for any ideas on the subject.